# fast api sqlalchemy table not created

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am trying to run my first Fast Api app, I tried to add "users" table, but nothing is being created in the postgres db

```
users = Table(
    "users",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("name", String(50)),
    Column("age", Integer),
    Column("birthdate", Date),
    Column("blood_type", String(3)),
    Column("blood_pressure", Integer),
    Column("created_at", DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M:%S"), nullable=False),
)
```

is there any issue with my code?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the beginning or the continuation of your code but you are intending to do is related to `SQLAlchemy`. As per [the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html), what you have implemented seems correct, but I presume you forgot some parts of the code. The below implementation is from the documentation, where your implementation fits it, except perhaps you  have forgotten `metadata.create_all()` part perhaps (I am trying to guess)? If not it would be great if you could perhaps share some errors or show the integral of your implementation with more details.

```py
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')

metadata = MetaData()

user = Table('user', metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('user_name', String(16), nullable=False),
    Column('email_address', String(60), key='email'),
    Column('nickname', String(50), nullable=False)
)

user_prefs = Table('user_prefs', metadata,
    Column('pref_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey("user.user_id"), nullable=False),
    Column('pref_name', String(40), nullable=False),
    Column('pref_value', String(100))
)

metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem these lines of codes helped me:

```
from . import crud, models, schemas
from .database import SessionLocal, engine

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```